# How to mock a typescript class with vitest

Tags: typescript, mocking, vitest

I have a class `A` that imports class `B` from a different module and instantiates it. In my test for class `A` I'd like to stub/mock some of the methods of class `B`.

Some example code:

```js
// Formatter.ts
export class Formatter {
   format(msg: string): string {
     return `--- [INFO] ${msg}\n`;
   }
}

// FormattedStore.ts
import {Formatter} from '@/Formatter'
export class FormattedStore implements Store {
   public store: string[];
   construct() {
     this.formatter = new Formatter();
     this.store = [];
   }

   write(msg: string): void {
      this.store.push(this.formatter.format(msg));
   }
}

// FormattedStore.spec.ts
import {FormattedStore} from '@/FormattedStore';
import {Formatter} from '@/Formatter'
import {vi, expect, test} from 'vitest';

vi.mock( '@/Formatter', () => ({ 
 Formatter: vi.fn() // What's the correct and type-safe way to mock this?
}));

test('it stores formatted message', () => {
   //  How do I mock the formatter here with the return 'formatted test message'?
   const store = new FormattedStore();
   store.write('TestMessage');

   expect(store.store[0]).toBe('formatted test message');
})
```

I know I could use constructor injection instead of mocking the module, but I have a case where that's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The package [vitest-mock-extended](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vitest-mock-extended) solves this:

```js
// FormattedStore.spec.ts
import {mock} from 'vitest-mock-extended';
import {FormattedStore} from '@/FormattedStore';
import {Formatter} from '@/Formatter'
import {vi, expect, test} from 'vitest';

vi.mock( '@/Formatter', () => ({ 
 Formatter: mock<Formatter>() // Mock class here
}));

test('it stores formatted message', () => {
   Formatter.format.mockReturnValue('formatted test message');  // provide return values here
   const store = new FormattedStore();
   store.write('TestMessage');

   expect(store.store[0]).toBe('formatted test message');
})
```